# Atari ST colour rendering

Tags: crt-monitor, color-display

In the late 80's, I had an interesting incident with an Atari ST that I've never really understood.

I was using some graphics software that I recall was very similar to the way Microsoft's Paint still works. It may have been "Degas". It was still relatively unusual to have a colour monitor at that point, but I had one - Philips I believe. It connected via the Atari standard monitor connector.

I created my own colour using an RGB value - bright lime green. Approximately equivalent to 128, 255, 0.

After some time of painting with various colours, my eyes started to tire and I turned down the brightness on the monitor. The lime green colour seemed to brighten! I turned down the brightness some more - the green got brighter!

Eventually, the brightness of the monitor was virtually black. What I realised was that the green was remaining the same and ignoring the overall brightness setting of the monitor. This gave the impression that the colour was in some way brighter than the monitor was able to produce. It was quite disconcerting at the time.

It seems that in some way, is was directly controlling the RGB values of the guns, bypassing the electronics of the monitor. How was that possible?

EDIT: I feel that my description isn't really putting across the experience, so I have mocked-up some equivalent screen-shots as if it happened on Paint.

Here I am, painting with my new Lime Green colour:

[image: Normal brightness]

I turn down the Brightness:

[image: Turned down a bit]

Experiment with turning to the lowest possible brightness:

[image: Lowest Brightness]

In the 2nd and 3rd images, I have replicated the effect by just redrawing the green shapes in the *original* colour, after having dimmed the image across the board. It is a remarkably good representation of the effect that I saw.

Comment: I wonder if it was Spectrum 512, which could display thousands of colors at once by scan line color cycling.

Comment: @JimNelson Sorry, what was Spectrum 512..?

Comment: A painting program for the Atari ST: https://doudoroff.com/atari/spectrum.html  It used a programming trick to coax the color monitor to display more colors than intended.

Comment: @JimNelson I see. It may have been, it was a long time ago. The name doesn't sound familiar, but I did have lots and lots of copied software for the ST. So you think that the programming trick somehow took direct control of the guns?

Comment: If it contributes anything: even though Atari were very much into aggressive pricing, which might suggest unusual non-standard solutions, I believe the RGB output is completely standard. It doesn’t do traditional monitor functions like brightness in software in order somehow to save $0.01 or anything like that. Alas this completes my relevant contributions.

Comment: Are you sure you turned down brightness, and not adjusting contrast?

Comment: "Brighter" might be an optical illusion. Probably it got more saturated instead, i.e. greener.

Comment: "artist rendering" of past experience (and lotsa white space) isn't exactly helpful here. Voting for close as it goes rapid OT.

Comment: Were you by any chance using a composite video output?  Some monitors could, if color gain was set to maximum while contrast and brightness were set to minimum, generate colors that were over 100% saturated, so if white would be (10%/10%/10%) and green should be (0%,10%,0%), i.e.. the sum of roughly (5%,5%,5%) and (-5%, +5%, -5%) a monitor might "compute" the color difference signal as (-25%,+25%, -25%), yielding (-20%,+30%,-20%) which would be displayed as (0%,30%,0%).  The luminance (roughly R/4+B/4+G/2) should still be 5%. but the fact that red and blue don't go negative would make it 15%.

Comment: @supercat I think this might be the answer. I've just done a bit of searching and I believe the monitor may well have been a Philips CM8833. I thought it just connected to the standard ST monitor socket - but I now think it may well have done so via a cable that had SCART connector on the monitor end. So, I assume that this had composite video on one of the pins...?

Comment: @Lefty: I wouldn't think a monitor would input SECAM composite video via SCART, but I can imagine that a monitor design which included both composite and RGB inputs but was derived from a composite-only monitor might convert RGB into separate luminance and color-difference signals (what today would be called "component video") and then use the composite-monitor back-end circuitry which would behave as described.

Comment: @Lefty: Out of curiosity, did the "Color" adjustment knob have any effect when using the SCART input?  If so, that would imply that the video was being processed within the monitor as a combination of luminance and color-difference signals.

Comment: @supercat I bow to your knowledge on the first part - we are well beyond my understanding now I'm afraid. As for the adjustments/knobs, I'm afraid that it was well over 30 years ago and I would have probably not been able to recreate it a week later! I seem to recall the monitor having Brightness and Contrast knobs, so it is very likely that I twiddled with both of them while trying to find a comfortable setting.

Comment: @Lefty: If it was SCART, though, that would suggest that the monitor could accept an RGB input, but may have been designed for viewing television broadcasts and its acceptance of RGB was to facilitate support by a variety of video equipment, rather than an effort to enhance picture quality.  Adapting typical a computer, video game, or similar device to encode color using the System Essentially Contrary to the American Method would have been difficult, especially since many such devices use slightly wonky scan rates but SECAM only works with one exact horizontal frequency.

Comment: @supercat I'm still having trouble understanding exactly what you are saying, but reading between the lines I have to mention that I strongly believe this monitor was aimed at the monitor market rather than TV. It was beige in colour for a start. Also, I am in the UK, not US, and I believe the monitor was bought in Europe (Netherlands), so if we're getting into the technical details of TV signals, then I guess we're talking PAL rather than SECAM...?

Comment: @Lefty: SCART was designed for the French market, which was SECAM.  I don't know much about the marketplace of monitors and television sets in Europe, but what you're describing sounds like a monitor generating luminance and color-difference signals, amplifying them separately, and then remixing them.

Answer (score 7):

The described behavior isn't particular to the Atari in particular, but is true of many monitors and television sets in general.  Turning up the brightness knob clockwise a certain amount will have the effect of increasing all color channels by a corresponding amount, and turning it counterclockwise will decrease all color channels likewise, except that once a color channel reaches zero any further decrease will have no effect.

If one requests a color of 100% green, 50% red, and 25% blue, and a moderate brightness and contrast settings that color would be output at 80%, 40%, and 20% of the monitor's maximum, then turning the brightness up might result in the monitor outputting (100%, 60%, and 40%), which would be more pale color than requested, while turning the brigntness down might yield (60%, 20%, 10%).

Comment: True, it all depends on the way how brightness is handled in the CRT's electronics. The computer is almost never involved.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Indeed it is monitor dependent, but if one has a particular monitor which is only used with one computer it could easily seem computer dependent, especially if that monitor is of an older design.  The interaction between color, brightness, and contrast knobs has changed over the years, with newer monitors being less prone to have a large "dead zone" at the bottom of the video signal range at lower brightness settings.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just the well-known optical illusion where a constant colour appears differently against darker or lighter backgrounds?

The [usual illustration](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Gradient-optical-illusion.svg) of this has a constant-colour grey rectangle superimposed on a background gradient.  The brain perceives it as light against a dark background, or dark against a light background.

In your case, you're apparently darkening both background and foreground. However (hand-waving here), the eye is most sensitive in the green region of the spectrum, so perhaps the perceived darkening is greater in the background, thus leading to the optical effect described.

Comment: Surely WHITE would be brighter than any colour of green you could conceive...?

Comment: Perhaps, but there my layman's grasp of psychochromatics is exceeded.